# Can't convert 'int' to string

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror, bubble-sort

I am trying to code the bubble sort algorithm and I am stumbling at the `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` and I have no clue as i've checked both `x` and `length` using `isinstance()` and they are both integers.

Here is my code so far:

```
x = 1
list1 = list(input("What numbers need sorting? Enter them as all one - "))
length = len(list1)
print(list1)
while True:
    for i in range(0,length):
        try:
            if list1[i] > list1[i+1]:
                x = list1[i]
                list1.remove(x)
                list1.insert(i+1,x)
                print(list1)
            if list1[i] < list1[i+1]:
                x += 1
                print(list1)
        except IndexError:
            break
    if x == length:
        print("The sorted list is - ",''.join(list1))
        break
```

Comment: Please do not alter a list while iterating over it. Furthermore you use `x` here for two purposes: to count sorted instances, and to swap elements.

Comment: You are trying to assign `x` a string value here: `x = list1[i]`. The list `list1` is a list of strings, not integers.

Comment: This code run correctly on python 3 , are you using this cod on python2 ?

Comment: Ohh yes I am using x twice Willem. So if I use `int(input())` and then create a list it should work? And I am using python 3 yes, Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the `join(list1)` call. `str.join` expects an **iterable of *strings***. Your `list1` is however a list of integers. So as a result it goes wrong.

You can fix the error itself by mapping the elements of the list to the `str` equivalent, by writing:

```
print("The sorted list is - ",''.join(map(str, list1))
```

But that being said, the code is quite error prone:

1. you add and remove items while iterating over the list;
2. you use `x` both to count elements that are ordered, and to swap elements;
3. you never reset `x` after a bubble loop, so you will count bubbles twice.
4. furthermore catching the `IndexError` is quite inelegant, since you can also limit the range of `i`.

Probably a more elegant solution is:

```
unsorted = True
while unsorted:
    unsorted = False  # declare the list sorted
                      # unless we see a bubble that proves otherwise
    for i in range(len(l)-1):  # avoid indexerrors
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            unsorted = True  # the list appears to be unsorted
            l[i+1], l[i] = l[i], l[i+1]  # swap elements

print(l)  # print the list using repr
```

Comment: So seeing as what others have said, change the `list(input()` into `int(input()` then convert into a list. And then use your method to map the elements and to swap elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`list1` is made up of integers (presumably; it depends on what the user types in but the code is mostly written as though it expects a list of integers) but you use `''.join` on it as though it contains strings:

```
>>> ''.join([0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
>>> ''.join(['0'])
'0'
>>>
```